# How to configure Wine to use Windows 8 or 10?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, windows, wine, configuration

I'm trying to start Katalon (https://www.katalon.com/) 32bit on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

That's why I use Wine (3.12 Staging).

I configure Wine to use Windows 10.

I opened winecfg with console mode : `user$ winecfg`

> Into Winecfg window > Windows version > Windows 10 or 8 > Apply > Ok

However, when I start Katalon with Wine (right click on .exe file > Open with Wine) the app is start with Windows XP.

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: You might have to logout and log back in (or reboot) to get it to take effect, if you just ran Wine and then `winecfg` after it the Wine processes haven't restarted yet to reflect the OS changes and might do this.

Comment: Also, Wine 'Staging' is no longer supported upstream or in Ubuntu, you need to use either `wine` from the repositories or the upstream `wine-stable` or `wine-devel` from upstream.  Perhaps you meant the development release (which is 3.12)?

Comment: @ThomasWard I restarted my computer but the problem isn't solved. Do you think the problem is due to my wine version (Staging)?

Comment: No, I think it's more likely your wine prefix is just not updating to win8/win10.  That might be a bug in Wine but I'm not entirely sure.  And you need to start referring to "Staging" as "Development" because there *is* no more "Wine Staging" anymore.

Comment: I will try to set wine prefix even if I don't have any idea how to do that. And I will remove "wine"package to install `wine-devel winehq-develsudo`. I hope it will works...

Comment: @ThomasWard do you know how can I change wine version? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.  I'd have to look into it.  Let me see if I can replicate what you're seeing once I'm home and in front of my testing environments to see if I can replicate what you're seeing with the version not changing.

Comment: @ThomasWard somebody probably stepped up to maintain `wine-staging` because I see releases on phoronix news site. Also "wine-development" is the latest usual wine *(e.g. 3.12)*, that is opposed to "feature-freezed" wine-stable *(e.g. 3.0.2)*. Also, to stop wine processes is enough `wineserver -k` command.

Comment: @NicolasLamblin anyway, I have downloaded a [random "system info" app](https://superuser.com/questions/15216/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-detailed-list-of-the-hardware-in-my-windows-box), set Win8 version at winecfg, and the app shows Win8. I'm on wine-staging 3.9. Check if you see the same — then you gotta test it with usual wine, if it's not working, report a bug. Katalon likely detects OS in a weird way. Also, consider asking the Katalon's support for GNU/Linux native app. If they  refuse, perhaps they could consider contributing patches to wine so that their app would work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

To change [Windows version](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winecfg#Windows_Version) to 10 using [Winetricks](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks), you can run:

```
winetricks -q win10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just call what winetricks does without using winetricks `wine winecfg -v win10`

example

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~$ winetricks -q win10
Executing mkdir -p /home/mike/.wine_bottles
Using winetricks 20210206 - sha256sum: 0f21da98811e0bfda16a7d6d6b8e860a9cedbd4e836c7dd9b02f068d3092ee2e with wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1) and WINEARCH=win32
Executing w_do_call win10
Executing mkdir -p /home/mike/.wine_bottles
Executing load_win10 
Executing wine winecfg -v win10
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/home/mike/.wine_bottles/line terminate
------------------------------------------------------
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~$
```